Minikube can't load large images into cluster
I am trying to load big local image into minikube cluster using minikube image load <image> command it gives me the following error:
$ minikube  image load ci-env:0.1.0
Killed

The image has size of 17.7GB.
I tried to increase the resources to cluster with:
minikube start --disk-size=70GB --memory=8GB --cpus=4

but the error is still there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
